# Creating input field from html table that has PHP value

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a page full of small html tables, each representing data from a database table. This is a one page print out report, so there are quite a few fields across these html tables, but only about 4 or 5 of them may need to be changed.

When the user chooses a record and the report is displayed, all the tables look great but I'm trying to find a way to edit and save the 4 or 5 that might need editing. I know I can create a form with inputs and turn certain table rows into inputs and then with a submit button I can attach a SQL statement to update those fields based on a primary key in the DB table.

How can I actually get these table rows to be editable inputs within a form? I've wrapped the whole page in a form and I even tried by wrapping just one table in a form as a test but I think the problem is my syntax for the table row.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
<form>
<table style="width:100%; border:none;
border-collapse:collapse;">

    <tr style="border:none;">
        <th style="border:none; text-align: left;" >Meter Test</th>
        <th style="border:none;">Test 1</th>
        <th style="border:none;">Test 2</th>
        <th style="border:none;">Test 3</th>
        <th style="border:none;">Test 4</th>
        <th style="border:none;">Test 5</th>
        <th style="border:none;">Test 6</th>
        <th style="border:none;">Test 7</th>
        <th style="border:none;">Test 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: none;" >
        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Test Rate GPM: </td>
        <td><? echo $row['test1TestRateGPM'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test2TestRateGPM'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test3TestRateGPM'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test4TestRateGPM'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test5TestRateGPM'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test6TestRateGPM'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" value = "<?php $row['test7TestRateGPM'];?>">
        <td><input type="text" value = "<?php $row['test8TestRateGPM'];?>">        </td>

    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

You can see i have the normal html table syntax but for the field I'm testing, I tried it by creating a line of php and doing it that way, but still no form on the web page.

Comment: You could use the `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: how would I use that in saving the changed field content to the database table by hitting the save button, though? Sorry, I've never used that

Comment: look into jquery datagrid

Comment: I can't use jquery, unfortunately. I have to find a way to do it with html and php

Comment: You use Javascript to retrieve the edited contents.

Comment: Another solution is to just put `<input>` fields in the table.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I'd like to do, and I'm attempting it currently. I think my syntax is just wrong because it's not showing up as editable on the webpage still.

Comment: It should be `<?php echo $row['test7TestRateGPM'];?>` you're missing the `echo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a simple input text field.
Do it like this:

```
<td><input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row['test1TestRateGPM'];?>"></td>
```

And make multiple of these.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this (with form tags around just this table) and it's still not editable on the web page

Comment: Can you explain what is still not editable? What I just wrote, you need to do for each `<td>` separately.

Comment: I did, but I only need 5 of the fields on this page to be editable, and that was an example of one of them. But the webpage just loads as a static table still. Updating my code with what you just gave me.

Comment: Missing `echo` in the PHP

Comment: But it should still be editable, it just won't have the old value showing.

Comment: How did you write it?

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it now. Had a stray ending tag but I removed it